# Nginx to RDS AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, networking, amazon-rds

so I have `Nginx` installed on top `EC2` instance.

I want to route any income requests to `RDS` `Postgres` AWS.

The issue is that I don't really know how to configure `Nginx` to route to a connection string that AWS RDS provides me.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a `stream` block, and then configure a `proxy_pass` inside a `server` directive with the FQDN of your RDS instance.

Comment: yes, just figure it out. Thx.